# Does there exist a graph with 5 vertices of degree 3 and all other vertices of degree 2 or 4?

Tags: graph-theory

Does there exist a graph with 5 vertices of degree 3 and all other vertices of degree 2 or 4?

Does there exist a graph with 5 vertices of degree 3 and all other vertices of degree 2 or 4?

Comment: Have you heard of the handshaking lemma? Have you heard of the handshaking lemma?

Comment: Yes, but it's an infinite graph.

Comment: That would've been helpful to originally include in the question.

Comment: The nature of the question should imply that we are referring to finite graphs.  Of course there are many strange things that can happen with infinite graphs (*such an infinite graph of course exists, consider three claw graphs with each claw extended infinitely in each direction*).  Recognizing the point that no such finite graph exists however is probably the purpose of the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Prove to yourself that given a (finite) undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, the sum of degrees of all vertices $$\sum_{v\in V}\deg(v) $$is even, and then we'll talk.